# Should I implement rvalue push function and should I use std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

As an exercise, I'm implementing a stack class in C++11.
This is the relevant code:

```
template <class T>
class stack
{
private:
    T * elements;
    std::size_t capacity;
    std::size_t count;

public:
    explicit stack(std::size_t capacity) : capacity(capacity)
    {
        elements = new T[capacity];
    };

    ~stack()
    {
        delete[] elements;
    };

    void push(const T & t)
    {
        if (capacity > count)
        {
            elements[count++] = t;
        }
    }

    void push(T && t)
    {
        if (capacity > count)
        {
            elements[count++] = std::move(t);
        }
    }
};
```

I'm using the class as following:

```
stack<std::string> stack_test(2);
stack_test.push("string1");

std::string string2 = "string2";
stack_test.push(string2);
```

As expected, the first push uses *push(T && t)*, while the second push uses *push(const T & t)*.

Should I implement the rvalue push (i.e. is *push(T && t)* needed to be implemented)?
And should I use std::move() in that?

Comment: You implemented both of rvalue and lvalue pushes already, what do you mean with `rvalue push` ?

Comment: @arnes: I think the OP is referring to a `const T &`. I'm not sure the `T &&` applies to both, lvalues and rvalues. Push is not a function template. By the time it's used (instatiated), it's an rvalue. I think the reason it works is because it creates a local copy and "moves" it. Not sure tho...

Comment: I think  you have done both overloads well.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos The first push creates a temporary that is move assigned in the `void push(T && t)` function. The second push copy assigns in `void push(const T & t)`. Both looks good.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Yep! I missed the first overload.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the two questions though. "_Should I implement the rvalue push?_"  - You already did. "_should I use std::move() in that?_" - Yes, otherwise it'd be copy assigned just like in your first overload.

Comment: initialized count=0; inside constructor. I checked your code, rvalue function implemented correctly, inside you can check t is null after move operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are storing `t` in both `push`es, you can have *one*

```
void push(T t)
{
    if (capacity > count)
    {
        elements[count++] = std::move(t);
    }
}
```

But really, you should be using `std::vector<T> elements;` (or `std::deque` / `std::list`), like how [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) does

Comment: What happens if what you pass in the `push` is a reference to an existing object that needs to remain in memory? I think you'll end up with two separate copies of the same object and one can be updated outside of the stack. I don't think this is a good approach tbh...

Comment: I don't get it. Won't such an implementation move the `string2` in the OP's example ? I don't think this is the expected behaviour...

Comment: I'm not sure I can use this, as string2 (in the example) could become invalid at some point in time, and invalidating the stack's content as well. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @HBv6 actually not, because `t` doesn't refer to `string2`, it is copy of `string2`, so it is movable.

Comment: @Fareanor no, the call `stack_test.push(string2);` will copy construct the parameter `t` from `string2`. They are independant objects

Comment: @Caleth what if `move assignment` is deleted  for `T` ?

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos However you call `push`, a new object `t` is constructed, which is the same as the original 2 overloads. There *is* one extra move construction in the first case

Comment: @Caleth: Not if it's a `const &` it wont.

Comment: @arnes if you've a `T` with a deleted move but not a deleted copy, you don't play well with containers

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos if you have a `const std::string &`, you can only copy it into the stack. There is a "copy `push`" and a "move `push`" in the question. This version combines both

Comment: @Caleth: Your approach works for this example, but if you were to pass a `const &` to that push then you're in for a huge surprise. Because of the copy and then the cast to `&&`, you will end up with 2 separate copies.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos no, you will have one copy and one move, because `t` is a independent object

Comment: @Caleth: I see what you are referring to. The OP copies the data in both cases, so sure. If he were to create another function which creates a stack of addresses, then it would have been a different story.

Comment: @Caleth At least, we should warn the readers that `T must be MoveAssignable. Also it must be CopyConstructible when push is called with lvalue expression.`

Comment: @Caleth by copying a temporary into 't' aren't you defeating the purpose of a move constructor? You eventually end up having the temporary which might be destroyed sometime down the line and a copy of it which then gets moved in the push...

Comment: So why the STL stack implementation has 2 interfaces for push()? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/push/

Comment: @HBv6 Rather than change the first overload in C++11, it added the second. It also *guarantees* the "extra" move doesn't happen, but it's probably elided. Note also that an implementation of `std::` might not have exactly those overloads, so long as the observable behaviour is as specified